# UnsatisfiedDependencyException Error with bean name Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm a novice using a microservice architecture and want to access a bean from another module which uses camunda (a read only business process tool (library)). The error unsatisfied dependency is coming from a camunda interface  yet I don't require any bean from camunda in my current module so i tried to exclude it with the code below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"}, excludeFilters={
 @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration.class)})
```

The current module won't start giving the stacktrace below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine': Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NotValidException: Filter name must not be null or empty: name is null; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NotValidException: Filter name must not be null or empty: name is null
```

Comment: Too little details to say exactly. The problem is in creating bean `processEngineFactoryBean`. A code of this bean and spring config related code would be helpful

Comment: processEngineFactoryBean belongs to camunda. I simply do not require this camunda library in my current module. It is used by the module that i added as a dependency. Now it makes my current module not start

Comment: I can access other modules very well accept the one with this processEngineFactoryBean. I use the code @Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"}

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove `excludeFilters`?

Comment: @IvanPronin i tried to add the excludeFilters to remove the error with no luck. I am having no problems with other modules using configuration and componentscan. But i don't know how to ignore this library when i use the module that uses it

Comment: I don't think you can ignore this library since it's as you say - is being used by another module within your system. Spring just can't create its context for all active modules.

Comment: Ok so what can you suggest to try do? I tried to add the camunda package to the @ComponentScan base packages but it still does not initialize the bean

Comment: solved it with the answer below thanks @IvanPronin

Comment: I was a little bit confused since you told that you need camunda in one of your modules. So you can't just exclude it from project.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was simple although it took a long time to solve. I managed to solve it with the code below:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.camunda.blablabla</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

All needed to do was to exclude all the camunda dependencies in the module dependency section. Silly me!

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml file?

Comment: sorry @HerilMuratovic, no longer working on that project

Comment: Glad it helped  :)